# Future Any does not conform with Future E

Tags: scala, future

I am having a problem in Scala when trying to return a result from a method.

I am using Play 2.6 and ReactiveMongo.

Error in the images bellow:

[image]

[image]

Could somebody give some clues?

Comment: The Future composition of the code is not really well structured, rather use for comprehension and check your types.

Comment: @cchantep yes, it is not clear, I bear in mind to use for comprehension, but I am not very skillful in Scala, yet. and do you know what is causing my issue?

Comment: Bad composition is prone to type error, specially `result.map` which give a `Unit` from `printStackTrace` and a `entity: E` otherwise, so only `Any` is coherent among those cases.

Comment: Putting code as an image without text is a really bad choice. Please, never do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Future.map](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L289) method is accepting a **function** to map the `Future`'s result, so for your code, it's mapping `result`'s `Future` result, equal to:

```
  result.map(writeResult: WriteResult => {
    case Success => entity
    case Failure(f) => f.printStackTrace()
  })
```

As the above code, you are trying to return `WriteResult` and `Unit`,so the `map` result type is `Any`, and return `Future[Any]` type. so the type mismatch compile error thrown.

Actually you need is: `result.map(writeResult: WriteResult => entity)`. and you can invoke `create` method like:

```
  val res = create(entity)
  res.onComplete {
    case Success(e) => println(e)
    case Failure(f) => f.printStackTrace()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you really want is `Future.transform` instead of `map`. Something like this

```
  val result: Future[WriteResult] = ??? 
  result.transform(_ => entity,
    e => {
      e.printStackTrace()
      e // or return here your custom wrapper exception
    })
```